# hexdump not formatting blank spaces as expected

Tags: hexdump

I'm trying to create a hexdump of 8 hexadecimal numbers per line.  I'm using the following command

```
hexdump -v -e '"\t" 7/1 "0x%02x, " 1/1 "0x%02x,\n"' booter_load_tu102.bin
```

This is supposed to output a tab, 7 hex numbers separate by a comma and a blank space, and then a final 8th number with a comma and end-of-line.  However, when I run this command, I get something not quite right:

```
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,0x00,
```

Why is there no blank space between the 7th and 8th number?  If I modify the command like this:

```
hexdump -v -e '"\t" 7/1 "0x%02x, " 1/1 " 0x%02x,\n"' booter_load_tu102.bin
```

(inserting a blank space before the final "0x%02x,") it works:

```
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
```

Why is hexdump not inserting a blank space after the 7th number?

Comment: because hexdump is smart, it internally removes the last spaces (from what I have tested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a single trailing whitespace at the end of a format group is discarded.
I guess for convenience reasons.

That makes your expression easier, because you can use an easier format string, consume and format all 8 bytes the same way, append a line break and still have the desired output:

`hexdump -v -e '"\t" 8/1 "0x%02x, " "\n"' booter_load_tu102.bin` worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks.  It's unfortunate that this behavior is not documented.

Answer (score 0):

As documented [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hexdump):

> If, either as a result of user specification or hexdump modifying the iteration count as described above, an iteration count is greater than one, no trailing whitespace characters are output during the last iteration.

There's no way to disable this behavior, but you can patch it by adding a `" "` after each such group, e.g.:

```
hexdump -v -e '"\t" 7/1 "0x%02x, " " " 1/1 "0x%02x,\n"' booter_load_tu102.bin
```